# Enviar los parametros al componente padre selecionando un radio button

Tags: javascript, vue.js, props, quasar, radio

Estoy trabajando en Quasar y tengo el siguiente problema: tengo ahora mismo una tabla en un popUp donde se le pasan los chartsSeries que son el nombre de las variables que hay en la grafica y en ese popUp tengo las siguientes funcionalidades cambiar el color de la variable a visualizar en la grafica y poder ocultarla en la grafica, y la ultima elegir el escala del ejeY. Que pasa para poder pasar los parametros de la escala de cada variable he creado un objeto mas en los props la de los parametros que es una array y sun numeracion de la array es exactamente igual que la de los chartsSeries. Quiero que al seleciona un Q-radio le envie al componente padre los parametros de esa varibale.

Quisiera hacer algo parecido al primer metodo de ocultar las variables que envia por un emit al componente padre el selected.value, pero aqui con los parametros

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui paso el codigo del popUp:

```
<template>
  <q-dialog persistent>
    <q-card class="settings-popup">
      <q-toolbar class="bg-primary">
        <q-btn flat v-close-popup round dense icon="close" />
        <q-toolbar-title>Configuración</q-toolbar-title>
      </q-toolbar>

      <q-card-section>
        <q-table
          :rows="chartSeries"
          :columns="columnas"
          row-key="name"
          selection="multiple"
          v-model:selected.sync="selected"
          @selection="manejarCambioCheckbox"
        >
          <template v-slot:body="props">
            <q-tr :props="props">
              <q-td>
                <q-checkbox
                  v-model="props.selected"
                />
              </q-td>
              <q-td class="name-cell">
                <p class="name-text">{{ props.row.name }}</p>
              </q-td>
              <q-td>
                <q-input
                  filled
                  v-model="props.row.color"
                  class="inputCambiarColor"
                  :style="{ backgroundColor: props.row.color }"
                >
                  <template v-slot:append>
                    <q-icon name="colorize" class="cursor-pointer">
                      <q-popup-proxy cover transition-show="scale" transition-hide="scale">
                        <q-color v-model="props.row.color" />
                      </q-popup-proxy>
                    </q-icon>
                  </template>
                </q-input>
              </q-td>
              <q-td class="name-cell">
                <q-radio v-model="props.row.rangoMaximo" val="escala" />
              </q-td>
            </q-tr>
          </template>
        </q-table>
      </q-card-section>
    </q-card>
  </q-dialog>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, ref, nextTick } from "vue";

const props = defineProps(["chartSeries", "parametros"]);

console.log(props)

const emit = defineEmits(['actualizarEstadoSeries']);

const columnas = [
  { name: "name", label: "Nombre", align: "left", field: "name" },
  { name: "color", label: "Color", align: "left", field: "color" },
  { name: "escala", label: "Escala", align: "left", field: "escala" },
];

const selected = ref(props.chartSeries);
  
const manejarCambioCheckbox = () => {
  nextTick(() => {
    emit("actualizarEstadoSeries", selected.value);
  });
};

</script>

<style scoped>
.settings-popup {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: white;
}

.name-cell {
  text-align: center;
}

.name-text {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
</style>
```

Y este es el objeto que se recibe por props el que me muestra el consol.log(props)

```
chartSeries: Proxy(Array)
   0: {name: 'esm1entrada', data: Array(144)}
   1: {name: 'hor1entrada', data: Array(145)}
   2: {name: 'esm1salida', data: Array(145)}
parametros: Proxy(Array)
   0: {id: 1, variableID: 1, rangoMaximo: 20000, rangoMinimo: 0}
   1: {id: 2, variableID: 2, rangoMaximo: 20000, rangoMinimo: 0}
   2: {id: 3, variableID: 3, rangoMaximo: 20000, rangoMinimo: 0}
```